# Unable to run mvn release:prepare from IntelliJ using bundled Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project in IntelliJ working with the bundled version of Maven however when I come to do a `release:prepare release:perform` directly from within the IDE I get the following error.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project XXXXXX: Maven execution failed, exit code: '126'
```

Within IntelliJ I am using a project specific JDK (JDK 8) which is different to my machine JDK (JDK 11). I also am using the bundled Maven 3 with IntelliJ 2020.1 but have no Maven installed on my machine outside of the IDE.

I don't use JDK 8 or Maven anywhere other than this one project so would like to not have to install the extra tools globally if I can get away with running then from within this one project in the IDE. Is that possible? I'm building a Jenkins plugin for context if that matters?

Question: What is exit code 126?

Question: In order to perform a `release:prepare release:perform` do I need to to install the bundled project specific tools on my machine as opposed to keeping them within my project in IntelliJ?

Edit: Running with `-x` or `--debug` yields this error:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/XXX/Development/XXXXX-plugin && /home/XXXX/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/201.7223.91/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn -s /tmp/release-settings2724175258197430802.xml clean install --no-plugin-updates -P jenkins
    /bin/sh: 1: /home/XXXX/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/201.7223.91/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn: Permission denied
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: Run again with `-X` to see the debug output.

Comment: Do you get this error when running any Maven goal or only one of the specified?

Comment: @Andrey just the one specified. If I, for example, run `release:rollback` that works fine. Same with most other goals I have tried.

Comment: @JFMeier there's more output but the same error. Is there anything specific I should be looking for? `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project XXXXX: Maven execution failed, exit code: '126'`.

Comment: There should be more details about the error, like e.g. a stacktrace. Just add the complete error to the question.

Comment: @JFMeier apologies I was looking at the wrong section. You're correct there was. I've updated the question with an edit. Permission denied. I've got Maven bundled in with IntelliJ. IntelliJ was installed via the Jetbrains Toolbox app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139236

Which is duplicated by: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157229 that contains the following workaround:

> Using a newly generated plugin project using the
>   maven-archytype-plugin, when I tried running the default integration
>   test, it failed due to the following error:
>
> ```
> /bin/sh: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn: Permission denied
> ```
>
> When checking the `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA
>   14.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/`:
>
> ```
> evil-jim-klo:lib2 jklo$ cd "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/"
> evil-jim-klo:bin jklo$ ls -l
> total 88
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin   183 Dec 21 04:08 m2.conf
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin  5063 Dec 21 04:08 mvn
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin  5985 Dec 21 04:08 mvn.bat
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin  5253 Dec 21 04:08 mvnDebug
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin  6167 Dec 21 04:08 mvnDebug.bat
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin  5539 Dec 21 04:08 mvnyjp
> ```
>
> Note none of the files are set to executable. The expectation is that
>   all maven binaries should be executable by default upon installation
>   or application update.
>
> I corrected the problem by performing:
>
> ```
> chmod a+x *
> chmod a-x m2.conf
> ```
>
> to produce the following permissions:
>
> ```
> evil-jim-klo:bin jklo$ ls -l
> total 88
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 jklo  admin   183 Dec 21 04:08 m2.conf
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jklo  admin  5063 Dec 21 04:08 mvn
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jklo  admin  5985 Dec 21 04:08 mvn.bat
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jklo  admin  5253 Dec 21 04:08 mvnDebug
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jklo  admin  6167 Dec 21 04:08 mvnDebug.bat
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jklo  admin  5539 Dec 21 04:08 mvnyjp
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local install of maven on your machine. You need to tell IntelliJ to use that version of maven in Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > "Maven home directory"